# How are SARIMA models (which are non-linear in coefficients) generally estimated?

Tags: time-series, estimation, arima, seasonality

Very simple question but couldn't find answer to this online.

Taking $(1,0,0)(1,0,0)_{12}$ as an example,

$$(1-\Phi B^{12})(1-\phi B)Y_t=\epsilon_t$$
$$\implies Y_t=\phi Y_{t-1} + \Phi Y_{t-12} - \phi\Phi Y_{t-13} + \epsilon_t$$

Clearly this model is non-linear in coefficients. So how to estimate this model(how is it generally done in softwares, such as R)?

Comment: Maximum likelihood estimation via state-space representation and Kalman filter. (This is of course too short and not detailed enough for an answer, thus posting as a comment.)

Comment: @RichardHardy: Thanks. Although I don't quite know state-space model estimation much, but I know that it can be used for estimating a whole lot of complicated models. But there should be other methods as well right? I read that non-linear models are often estimated iteratively. How is that done?

Comment: I guess EM algorithm is applicable.